# Can you have alternating series where nth term approaches zero, yet sequence is NOT decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=K}^\infty a_n $$

if $a_n = (-1)^n b_n$  where $b_n \ge0$

1) and $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}b_n=0$

2) and ${b_n}$ is a decreasing sequence

then $\sum_{n=K}^\infty a_n$ converges

What is an example of the terms approaching zero, yet not being a decreasing sequence?

Comment: $b_{2n}=\frac 1{2n}$, $b_{2n+1}=\frac 1{n}$.

Comment: I don't follow what you wrote.

Comment: I was giving an example of a sequence for which the terms go to $0$ but the sequence is not decreasing.  My sequence starts at $b_2=\frac 12$ and goes $\{\frac 12, 1, \frac 14,\frac 12, \frac 16, \frac 13, \frac 18, \frac 14,\dots\}$

Comment: Still trying to understand your subscripts.   When $n=1, b_{2n} = b_2 = 1/2$   When $n=2, b_{2n} = b_4 = 1/4$   Where does that go?  Your $b_4 = 1/2$  How does the $b_{2n+1}$ come into play?    It looks like you're defining 2 different sequences.

Comment: I am defining $b_k$ for all $k>1$.  my rule says:  if $k$ is even then $b_k=\frac 1k$.  If $k$ is odd then $b_k=\frac 2{k-1}$.  Thus $b_1$ is undefined.  $b_2=\frac 12$, $b_3=\frac 2{3-1}=1$, $b_4=\frac 14$, $b_5=\frac 2{5-1}=\frac 12$, and so on.

Comment: You asked for "an example of the terms approaching zero, yet not being a decreasing sequence".

Comment: Is this possible to do without a piecewise style function?

Comment: The posted solution you accepted gives a continuous example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about
$$b_n=\frac1n(1+\sin(\pi n/2)).$$

Comment: So it would generally be some sort of oscillating trig function?

Comment: That  certainly would work. Lulu's answer works just as well.

Comment: Revisiting this.  Tim, how did you come up with that clever equation!?!